# Recursive return

Tags: python, recursion

```
def algae(S, n):
    """
    Print S rewritten with the algae rule to recursion depth n
    """
    al = {'A': 'AB', 'B': 'A'}
    # Base case
    if n == 0:
        return S
    # Transform each symbol in S
    for symbol in S:
        S += algae(al[symbol], n - 1)

print(algae('A', 5))
```

Hi, can anyone explain why when printing the outcome of this function I am receiving the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

This is referring to line 11 (S += algae(al[symbol], n - 1))

Comment: if n != 0, your function returns nothing.  That's why you are getting a `NoneType` error. Right away you are calling algae(x, 4), which isn't going to return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

This is a working version of your script:

```
def algae(S, n):
    """
    Print S rewritten with the algae rule to recursion depth n
    """
    al = {'A': 'AB', 'B': 'A'}
    if n == 0:
        return S
    # Make a new string to build on
    mystr = ""
    for symbol in S:
        # Add the translation to the new string
        mystr += al[symbol]
    # Recursively call the function, passing in the string
    return algae(mystr, n-1)

print(algae('A', 5))
```

Output:

```
ABAABABAABAAB
```

---

Note: If you want, you can make this a lot more efficient like  @Blckknght said:

```
def algae(S, n):
    """
    Print S rewritten with the algae rule to recursion depth n
    """
    al = {'A': 'AB', 'B': 'A'}
    if n == 0:
        return S
    mystr = "".join(al[c] for c in S)
    return algae(mystr, n-1)

print(algae('A', 5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the output should infact be: `ABAABABAABAAB` what else is wrong?

Comment: @user2850514 - Ah yes, your algorithm was a little off.  See my edit.

Comment: Note that a more "Pytonic" way of creating the new string would be `mystr = "".join(al[c] for c in S)`. Strings are immutible, so every `+=` you do to them requires a copy of the whole string, which can be very slow if the string gets long. CPython has a special optimization to make it faster some of the time, but you should not rely on that implementation specific behavior.

Comment: @Blckknght - I thought about adding that myself, but the OP seems like a newbie so I didn't want to overwhelm him.  I'll mention it though.

Answer (score 3):

When `n != 0`, your code falls off the end of the function. In Python, that's equivalent to returning `None`. You need to add a `return` statement for the recursive case.

Comment: Adding a `return` returns something but unfortunately not the write thing. I have added it below `S += algae(al[symbol], n - 1)` outside the loop.

Comment: @user2850514: Sorry, I really meant that you have to return *something* (probably `S`). A bare `return` also returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where `n` isn't 0, `algae` never `return`s anything, so Python implicitly gives it a return value of `None`.  The next `algae` call up then tries to do `S += None` because of this, which produces the error.  Add `return S` to the end of your function to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "return S" at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Working version without recursion (never liked recursion)

```
    def algae(S, n):
    al = {'A': 'AB', 'B': 'A'}
    for i in range(n):
        newS = ''
        for i in range(len(S)):
            newS += al[S[i]]
        S = newS
    return S

print(algae('A', 5))
```

Comment: I'm not certain (so your answer _is_ valid), but I think the OP needs to use recursion because this is a school assignment.

Comment: Not necessarily an assignment but I am working on a personal recursive based project right now and am having troubles with this.